# error serverity 16 on mssql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I just don't know why this happen:

```
$res = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
```

generate error:

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Invalid object name 'mytable'. (severity 16) in D:\wamp\www\cliN4\cops.php on line 201
```

Then I modified the code to:

```
$res = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE year = '2013' ORDER BY mytable_id");
```

It's OK.

I've check the database and the connection, it's fine. But I don't know why this happen. What's wrong?

thank you

Comment: What is the schema of `mytable`? Is it `dbo` or something else?

Comment: Yes.it is dbo. On my database the name 'dbo.mytable'